# How to align two divs underneath each other? (Top div is being cut in half)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align two div's vertically, I know how to do this. But another issue is coming up, the div above ("top-bar") is being cut in half when I place the second div below it and I have no reason why. Should I use position:absolute to solve this? I try to avoid using this however whenever I can. Thanks!

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.homepage-window {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-bar {
    width: 18%;
    background-color: #2E3E4E;
}

.top-bar {
    height: 8%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
}

.bottom-bar {
    margin-top: 20%;
    height: 8%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
}
/*border-top: 0.5px solid lightgrey;*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Homepage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<head>
<title>Cold-Ops Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="homepage-window">
    <div class="nav-bar">

    </div>
    <div class="top-bar">

    </div>
    <div class="bottom-bar">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there more Css included in home.css or is that the CSS you have here?

Comment: @user2796515 Nope, that's all the CSS I have.

Comment: They are not being cut in half, the three elements are being laid out left-to-right in a `flex` container. Since they both have `width:100%` the browser has to shrink them down so they will fit.

Comment: Does the pic that you posted show the div cut in half? You mean cut in half horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your top-bar and bottom-bar div in another wrapper div with width :100%;

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="top-bar">

   </div>
   <div class="bottom-bar">

   </div>
</div>
```

In your case all 3 divs are placed in a flex container, its aligning them in the same row. Thats why You need to keep the top-bar and bottom-bar div in another div container.

```css
 
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #EFEFEF;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.homepage-window {
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
}

.nav-bar {
width: 18%;
background-color: #2E3E4E;
}

.top-bar {
height: 8%;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
}

.bottom-bar {
margin-top: 20%;
height: 8%;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Homepage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<head>
<title>Cold-Ops Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="homepage-window">
<div class="nav-bar">

</div>
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="top-bar">

    </div>
    <div class="bottom-bar">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```